# необычное поведение цикла for в go

Tags: golang, словари, for

Я только начал изучать golang и столкнулся с очень любопытным поведением цикла for в нем. В коде я просто перебираю карту со вложенной картой:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {

el := map[string]map[string]string{
    "H": {
        "fullname": "hydrogen",
        "state":    "gas",
    },
    "He": {
        "fullname": "Helium",
        "state":    "gas",
    },
    "Li": {
        "fullname": "Lithium",
        "state":    "solid",
    },
    "Be": {
        "fullname": "Beryllium",
        "state": "solid",
    },
}
for i, element := range el {
    fmt.Println("elements name: ", i)
    fmt.Println(" properties: ")
    for j, prop := range element {
        fmt.Println(j, " : ", prop)
        }
    }
}
```

на выходе я вижу закономерное:

```
elements name:  H
 properties: 
fullname  :  hydrogen
state  :  gas
elements name:  He
 properties: 
fullname  :  Helium
state  :  gas
elements name:  Li
 properties: 
fullname  :  Lithium
state  :  solid
elements name:  Be
 properties: 
fullname  :  Beryllium
state  :  solid
```

но если в карте оставить только два элемента, например вот так:

```
el := map[string]map[string]string{
        "H": {
            "fullname": "hydrogen",
            "state":    "gas",
        },
        "He": {
            "fullname": "Helium",
            "state":    "gas",
        },
    }
```

То результат выглядит неожиданно, т.к. "fullname" второго элемента стал вдруг вторым, а не первым свойством:

```
elements name:  H
 properties:
fullname  :  hydrogen
state  :  gas
elements name:  He
 properties:
state  :  gas
fullname  :  Helium
```

Выполняется код в обычной cmd-консоли в windows. С чем связанно такое любопытное поведение цикла?

Answer (score 3):

Golang не гарантирует порядок элементов `map` при обходе.
Более того, там специально сделана случайная последовательность элементов.

https://golang.org/ref/spec#Map_types

> For statements with range clause
>
> 3. The iteration order over maps is not specified and is not guaranteed to be the same from one iteration to the next.

Answer (score 2):

да, как верно отметили выше, порядок ключей в словаре(map) отсутствует.

я бы рекомендовал использовать структуру для значения в словаре, т.о. достаточно будет одного цикла, а значение по ключу можно получать используя поля структуры, в целом структуры классная вещь, очень полезно ими пользоваться. Вот пример кода, только форматирование поправьте самостоятельно, я же не знаю как именно нужно).

```
package main

import  "fmt"


func main() {

type field struct {
    fullname string
    state    string
}

el := map[string]field{
    "H": {
        "hydrogen",
        "gas",
    },
    "He": {
        "Helium",
        "gas",
    },
    "Li": {
        "Lithium",
        "solid",
    },
    "Be": {
        "Beryllium",
        "solid",
    },
}
for i, element := range el {
    fmt.Println("elements name: ", i)
    fmt.Println(" properties: ")

    fmt.Println(element.fullname, element.state)

}
```

}

[Этот код в песочнице golang](https://play.golang.org/p/juRrkt6pY2j)